# How to add items to ListView with .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, listview, maui

I want to add items to a ListView with .NET 7 + C#. Is there a way to do this programmatically with C#? The reason is the app will receive data from a server and I want to add parts of the data to the listview.

I have read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/listview?view=net-maui-7.0
but there is no information on how to do this with C# completely, neither is there anything I can find on Google (except by installing packages, which I want to avoid). Maybe I am misunderstanding something.

I would appreciate an example.

Comment: Did you try something like ListView.Items.Add()?

Comment: Please tag the full platform details! - From the link it looks as if you are using App UI (.NET MAUI) ListView- This seems to be fully data bound and you would have to add the new items to the underlying datasource.

Comment: -Tags edited. 
-Yes, I tried with ListView.Items.Add() but then this error shows up: "CS1061 'ListView' does not contain a definition for 'Items' and no accessible extension method 'Items' accepting a first argument of type 'ListView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".

-And I am using App UI (.NET MAUI) ListView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `ListView` gets its data from its `ItemsSource`, which is an `IEnumerable`.  To add data dynamically, just `Add` elements to the data source

```
ObservableCollection<string> myData = new ObservableCollection<string>();

MyListView.ItemsSource = myData;

...

myData.Add("new item");
```